# dns resolve for 2 IPs with same reference

Tags: dns

We having following situations:
On a server, we have to set 2 IPs which will be refereed to the same fqdn.
in the application which is running on the server, we are configuring the FQDN. Once there is problem with access to one IP (based on the FQDN), the server will use the second IP assigned to the same FQDN:

example:
`/etc/hosts` will contain

```
1.1.1.1 server1.google.com
1.1.2.1 server1.google.com
```

once there is problem to access to 1.1.1.1, the server will use the server1.google.com as 1.1.2.1

Can we use such a thing? Is there some other option?

Comment: Relevant? http://serverfault.com/questions/60553/why-is-dns-failover-not-recommended

Answer (score 1):

/etc/hosts will not round-robin. It just returns the first match it finds.

If you want round-robin resolution, you'll need a full DNS server doing it.

Furthermore, round-robin DNS is not a good tool for load-balancing, which is what you want. As convenient as it seems, name resolution is not the layer for doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If don't want or cannot change your application, you will have to put a load-balancing layer somewhere in between the server running the application and two servers you want to connect. This will allow to :

- keep using the same DNS name and even same IP address (the load-balancer will create a virtual IP)
- be directed to all the servers in turn
- avoid to connect to any server that would disappear in case of problem
- allow authentication session to be kept with the same destination, if necessary

For load-balancing solutions, you may have a look to the [Linux LVS project](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/).

You can change also your application, if this is supported, to give both IP in any connect string. The first IP will be used and if it is not responding, the second one will be. But this depends a lot on the language used to build the application. E.g. this is possible with Java Database connector.